# Can multiple persistence volume claims bind to same persistence volume in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have setup one persistence volume with 100Gi capacity and setup two different persistence volume claims with 10Gi capacity each in Kubernetes.  The first PVC in bond to the PV but the second one is in Pending state.  And the "kubectl get pvc" shows the Capacity of the first PVC is 100Gi.

Is it possible to bind multiple PVCs to the same PV?  And why the capacity show in "kubectl get pvc" is the capacity of PV, not the capacity of PVC?

thanks,
Jerry

Answer (score 1):

No thats not possible - one claim will bind the available volume and the other will be pending until another volume is available.
Cheers